# Handling oauth redirects in angular 2+ SPA preventing refresh

Tags: angular, redirect, oauth

So basically what I have is an angular 4 SPA. I am trying to integrate the gmail api which uses oauth. I have to specify a redirect url while connecting to the authorization url.

The SPA needs to go to the authorization url(which is external url of google in this case) which will ask user to give permission. Then once permission is given, the gmail api will redirect to our application(SPA).

I am wondering how do I implement this flow without having a page reload/refresh.Since we have to go to the authorization url, we would need to leave our angular SPA. 
Also if there is a redirect, then surely the redirect url will be loaded in the browser. So how do I avoid this page refresh on redirection in oauth?

Comment: You can try running the auth in a popup window. Do you have a specific reason to avoid a page refresh?

Comment: @Raven won't a page refresh defeat its purpose of being an SPA?

Comment: That's mostly user experience. If you look at most other sites using a similar OAuth they will usually redirect to the other site and then initialize again based on the redirect Url and metadata in the request. You want the user to properly visit the other page so they can verify it's validity.

Comment: @Raven I would prefer running auth in a popup or a different window and let it communicate the result of oauth to the original SPA. Yeah its more about UX than about anything else.